# Firebase quick start throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, firebase

I added the app to Firebase console and added google json file to app folder.
Then when I try to launch the app it crashes with the following message.

Thanks in Advance.

Error:

> 07-27 13:18:21.000 26362-26362/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      Process: com.google.samples.quickstart.config, PID: 26362
>                                                      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzby.(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
>                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5855)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5447)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5386)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.google.samples.quickstart.config-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.google.samples.quickstart.config-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.samples.quickstart.config-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzby.(Unknown Source) 
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source) 
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751) 
>                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726) 
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5855) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5447) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5386) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.samples.quickstart.config"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.samples.quickstart.config" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in Android Studio 3 Beta 5, but not in Android Studio 3 and preview 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean and rebuild your project. Then start it without instant run.

Comment: @SaiKiran Have you put  casspath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' into dependencies in top-level gradle build file?

Comment: I was using Android Studio 3 when I opened the same project in Android Studio 2 .x it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by first adding [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) and then clean the project and rebuilding it.